# Handling null pointers and throwing exceptions in streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, nullpointerexception

Let's consider a `Parent` class which contains only one `Integer` attribute.
I created 6 objects of parent class and  with one null variable. Then I added these objects to a list.

I want to retrieve the corresponding object by the value of `Integer` attribute.
I used Java 8 Streams for it.

```
Predicate<Parent> predicate = e -> e.getId() == 100; // sample attribute value
result = list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I got `NullPointerException`, so I edited the code:

```
list.stream().filter(h -> h!=null).filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I want to throw an exception if any of the object is null. If no objects in the  list is null, then I want to retrieve the corresponding object from list.

How can I achieve this using a single statement using Java 8 Streams?

Comment: Your first answer was doing exactly this only right? Why did you filter out the `null` values then?

Comment: Codebender: No I don't want to know null pointer exception. I want to know myown exception.

Comment: You will have to build collectors to do this. Have a look here. https://github.com/hgwood/java8-streams-and-exceptions

Comment: Why not simply catch the NPE, wrap it in your own exception, and throw that exception on?

Comment: Use Optional in Java 8

Comment: @Buurman: It is actually pretty dangerous to catch a NPE: What if there is a programming error in the code and there is a NPE for some other reason? Then it will get mistaken for an absent `Parent` in the list.

Comment: @Lii: that’s easy to check: `catch(NullPointerException ex){ if(list.contains(null)) throw new CustomException(); else throw ex; }`, that way other NPEs are retained. The check has some costs but that doesn’t matter as it is only performed in the erroneous case.

Comment: @Holger: Hm... I don't really think it's a good practice. There is a slight chance that there is an unexpected null dereference that is triggered when the list also contains null. I would stick to the rule of always avoiding to catch NPEs. It is too easy to get wrong since they can be thrown basically anywhere. Tricky example: If `e.getId()` happen to return a null `Integer`.

Comment: @Lii and @ Holger: You are both correct of course. Though I wouldn't *avoid* catching Exceptions if they could then bubble up to the user interface. Always handle exceptions if they can be shown to the user, even if it's just by logging the exception and showing a general error message.
@ ManuJoy: Why is it so important to have a *single* statement? You can also just check the (intermediate) list for null values, throw a custom exception if that's the case, and continue on otherwise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JB Nizet answer is okay, but it uses `map` only for its side effects and not for the mapping operation, which is kind of weird. There is a method which can be used when you are solely interested in the side effects of something, such as throwing an exception: `peek`.

```
List<Parent> filtered = list.stream()
    .peek(Objects::requireNonNull)
    .filter(predicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you want your own exception just put a lambda in there:

```
List<Parent> filtered = list.stream()
    .peek(p -> { if (p == null) throw new MyException(); })
    .filter(predicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

#### Note about non exhausted streams

Note that, regardless of if you use `map` or `peek`, you have to make sure that the stream is consumed in its entirety for all the elements to be checked! Otherwise the exception might not be thrown even if there are null elements.

Examples where all elements might not be checked:

- `limit` is used.
- `allMatch` is used.
- The stream is filtered BEFORE the null check pipeline stage.

---

#### Checked Exceptions

If your exception is checked you can either check for null beforehand, if you don't mind traversing the list twice. This is probably best in your case, but might not always be possible.

```
if (list.contains(null)) throw new MyCheckedException();
```

You could also throw an unchecked exception in your stream pipeline, catch it and then throw the checked one:

```
try {
    ...
        .peek(p -> { if (p == null) throw new MyException(); })
    ...
} catch (MyException exc) {
    throw new MyCheckedException();
}
```

Comment: Objects.requireNonNull() also throws `NullPointerException` only. You need to write a custom action to throw your own exception.

Comment: OP's question was not to use NPE, so you still need something like  Consumer<Parent> con = e -> {if (e.getId() == null) throw new SomeException(); };

Comment: Also, I guess in both the answers, the `MyException` should be an unchecked exception. Or the compiler doesn't allow it...

Comment: @Codebender: That's right. If it must be checked then a sneaky throw method might be warranted.

Comment: The sneaky throw doesn’t work the way you have written. In your code, the compiler will perfectly infer the right checked exception and complain. Besides that, `peek` is meant to support debugging but not to be part of production code logic.

Comment: @Holger, to my opinion using `peek` in production code might be ok if you setup the processed element for further operation and have no other side-effects like `names.stream().map(Node::new).peek(n -> n.setParent(this)).forEach(this::addNode)` instead of longer `names.stream().map(name -> {Node n = new Node(name); n.setParent(this); return n;}).forEach(this::addNode)`.

Comment: @Holger "_The sneaky throw doesn’t work_": You're right, I made a mistake I've updated. "_Besides that, `peek` is meant to support debugging_": The documentation says "_This method exists **mainly** to support debugging_". If there are no practical problem with it I think it is okay.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: of course, using `map` for executing a Consumer is not better. But why comparing two wrong approaches anyway? In your example, the correct solution would be `names.stream().map(Node::new).forEach(n -> {n.setParent(this); addNode(n);})`

Comment: @Holger: I'm with Tagir about the use of the `peek` method. The reason it is mainly for debugging is not because there is some taboo against using it, but because it is mainly useful for that. But every once in a while it is useful for something else, and then there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: NEVER USE Stream#peek method in production code. As Javadoc says peek was "mainly to support debugging ...where the stream implementation is able to optimize away..., the action will not be invoked for those elements." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)

Comment: @epox: That's just you inventing an arbitrary rule for yourself. Even if `peek` is mostly useful for debbuging it is fine to use it if you are aware of how it works and that is what you need. There is nothing in the documentation that says otherwise.

Comment: @Lii, please read till the end. The key API point is: **"...the action will not be invoked for those elements."** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)

Answer (score 4):

Let’s start with the simplest solution:

```
if(list.contains(null)) throw new MyException();
result = list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you suspect the list to contain `null`s and even have a specialized exception type to flag this condition, a pre-check is the cleanest solution. This ensures that such condition doesn’t silently remain if the predicate changes to something that can handle `null`s or when you use a short-circuiting stream operation that may end before encountering a subsequent `null`.

If the occurrence of `null` in the list still is considered a programming error that shouldn’t happen, but you just want to change the exception type (I can’t imagine a real reason for this), you may just catch and translate the exception:

```
try {
    result = list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
catch(NullPointerException ex) {
    if(list.contains(null)) // ensure that we don’t hide another programming error
        throw new MyException();
    else throw ex;
}
```

This works efficient under the assumption that `null` references do *not* occur. As said, if you suspect the list to contain `null` you should prefer a pre-check.

Comment: I'll add my comment about catching NPEs here also: I don't really think it's a good practice. I would stick to the rule of always avoiding to catch NPEs. It is too easy to get wrong since they can be thrown basically anywhere. In this example there is a slight chance that there is an unexpected null dereference that is triggered when the list also contains null. Tricky example: If `e.getId()` happens to return a null `Integer`.

Comment: @Lii: that isn’t an issue since, if you have two programming errors, it isn’t really important which one gets flagged. As I already said in the answer, this solution is only for use cases, where the other exception type has similar semantics (programming error) as the NPE and that I therefore don’t see a real value in changing the exception type. And I don’t know whether this is really worse than abusing `peek`  or using sneaky throwing technique…

Comment: That's why I threw another exception class in my solution which surrounded the stream operations with a try-catch.

Comment: But having a null element in the list is likely (or at least not necessarily) not a programming error. Just an exceptional condition which should be reported by an exception.

Comment: See the first part of my answer. If having a null element in the list is likely not a programming error, a pre-check should be used. I clearly said in the answer that the second part only applies “if the occurrence of `null` in the list still is considered a programming error” (despite the exception type translation).

Comment: Ah, yes you did, sorry! Then there is only the slight problem of mixing up the programming errors, which, as you noted above, might not be something to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

## ::map vs ::peek

Use **`Stream#map`** and NEVER USE *`Stream#peek`* method in production code. As Javadoc says *peek* was *`mainly to support debugging ...where the stream implementation is able to optimize away..., the action will not be invoked for those elements.`* REF: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer))

## java.utils.Objects#requireNonNull

```
  list.stream()
      .map(Objects::requireNonNull)
      .filter(predicate)
```

This code clearly separates the validation part and filter part. It will contain "requireNonNull" frame in the exception call stack. Although, by java.util design, it'll rise NPE exceptoin type. REF: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-). SRC: [openjdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java#l201)

---

## requireNonNull with a static message

```
  list.stream()
      .map(item -> requireNonNull(item, "Null item in the list."))
      .filter(predicate)
```

> import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

REF: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-). SRC: [openjdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java#l226)

---

## requireNonNull with a custom message supplier

```
  list.stream()
      .map(item -> requireNonNull(item, () -> "Expected non-null items. Was: " + list))
      .filter(predicate)
```

REF: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.util.function.Supplier-). SRC: [openjdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java#l288)

---

## custom validator

```
  list.stream()
      .map(this::requireItemNonNull)
      .filter(predicate)
      ...


private Parent requireItemNonNull(Parent item) {
  if (null == item) throw new IllegalStateException("Expected: non null items. Was: " + this.list);
  return item;
```

---

## validate all

If you only need to validate all items, use a collector at the end. E.g. `toArray` as stream postpones actual iteration until the "collect" time:

```
  list.stream()
      .map(this::validateItemNonNull)
      .toArray();
```

Comment: The Javadoc of `peek` uses the phrase "exists mainly to support debugging" because the method is mainly useful for that, not because it is forbidden to use it for anything else. Nowhere does it say that you must "never" use it for production code. It is fine to use it in production code in the right situations (although those are rare).

Comment: Your solution with `map` has exactly the same problems a the Javadoc of `peek` describes: The operation might not be invoked for all elements if the stream is not fully consumed. On top of that the solution with `map` has yet another problem: It uses `map` only for side effects, without performing any actual mapping, which is surprising and weird. `peek` is the perfect choice for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function<Parent, Parent> throwingIdentity = p -> {
    if (p == null) {
        throw new MyException();
    }
    return p;
};

List<Parent> filtered = 
    list.stream()
        .map(throwingIdentity)
        .filter(predicate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```