# How to process remaining elements in the list of Java 8 streams, when exception occurs at one element?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-stream

The main thing here is to retrieve the ids of employees whose name length > 3. but employee 4 has null as name, so the Null pointer exception will be raised. How to skip employee 4
which raises exception and processes remaining elements in the list instead of terminating the list. The desired output can be [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]

below is the code:

```java
public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        createEmpList(empList);
        List<Integer> employeeIds = empList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getName().length() > 3)
                .map(x -> x.getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(employeeIds);
    }

    private static void createEmpList(List<Employee> empList) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("siddu",   1, "Hyderabad", 70000);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Swami",   2, "Hyderabad", 50000);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("Ramu",    3, "Bangalore", 100000);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(null,      4, "Hyderabad", 65000);
        Employee e5 = new Employee("Krishna", 5, "Bangalore", 160000);
        Employee e6 = new Employee("Naidu",   6, "Poland",    250000);
        Employee e7 = new Employee("Arun",    7, "Pune",      45000);
        Employee e8 = new Employee("Mahesh",  8, "Chennai",   85000);

        empList.add(e1);
        empList.add(e2);
        empList.add(e3);
        empList.add(e4);
        empList.add(e5);
        empList.add(e6);
        empList.add(e7);
        empList.add(e8);
    }
}
```

Comment: `filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: or check for nulls in the code to avoid the NPE

Comment: And generally: by expanding the filter logic to incorporate a try-catch which returns `false` in any `catch` case.

Comment: it shoud never be possible to write an employee without a name, it creates inconsistencies among the rest of the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling null pointers and throwing exceptions in streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334326/handling-null-pointers-and-throwing-exceptions-in-streams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code handles all exceptions dynamically. Thanks

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        createEmpList(empList);
        List<Integer> employeeIds = empList.stream().filter(x -> {
            try {
                return x.getName().length() > 3;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

        }).map(x -> x.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(employeeIds);
```

Output : `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Answer (score 2):

You can just add filter   `.filter(x-> x.getName() != null)` like that:

```
List<Employee> modifiedEmpList = empList.stream()
   .filter(x-> x.getName() != null)
   .filter(x -> x.getName().length() > 3)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I answer your question. You ask the next question in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitrii Bykov

Comment: Or [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)): `.filter( x -> Objects.nonNull( x.getName() ) )`

Comment: By the way, in Java 16+ we can shorten `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to `.toList()`.